# SC StartService FAILED 1058

Tags: c, windows, driver

I am trying to install a driver as a driver service (i.e., using `sc create` or equivalent) but when I try to start it (using `sc startservice`) I always get error 1058:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

It's really getting on my nerves now, I don't know what to do.

I also tried to follow the tutorial [Write a universal Hello World driver (KMDF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx) but when building I get

> 1   error : No such host is known

when I've checked the "Enable Deployment" Checkbox under Properties->Driver Install like in the tutorial.

(Without this checkbox it builds successfully, but then I get error 1058 again.)

I would like to install it as a driver service, not the way it is done in the tutorial.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that the driver was the wrong sort to be started manually, i.e., because of the way it was designed and/or configured, it had to be started by the Plug and Play system in response to the presence of a matching hardware device.

The OP reports that changing the driver type from KMDF to WDM resolved the problem.

Comment: yes :changing the driver type from KMDF to WDM resolved the Problem, thx